# Rails scope/class method selecting virtual attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, kaminari, scopes

I'm currently using the `has_scope` gem in conjunction with scopes/class methods on models to filter result sets returned to my UI.

I have a model `Task` which I'd like to be able to filter by `status` -- a virtual attribute on the model.

The `Task` model has a few attributes which you might need to know about

```
uuid: Generated by SecureRandom
running: A boolean
success: A boolean
started_at: DateTime
```

The `status` is calculated as such:

```
def status
    if running?
        'Running'
    elsif started_at.nil?
        'Queued'
    elsif success?
        'Finished'
    else
        'Failed'
    end
end
```

Ignoring the fact that this is probably not an ideal way of doing this, I have currently implemented the `status` filtering method like so:

```
def self.by_status(status)
  records = all.select {|s| s.status == status}
  where(uuid: records.map(&:uuid))
end
```

I cannot return just the results from `select` as it's of type `Array` as opposed to an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, hence my `where` hackery. For context the reason I cannot/do not want to return an array is the result-set is passed to `kaminari` for pagination.

*Please note*: The method I currently use meets my requirements, but I don't like the way it's done. I feel like there should be a better way.

Can anyone suggest a better `by_status` method for returning an `ActiveRecord::Relation`?

tl;dr:
Need a class method to return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` filtering on a virtual attribute.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it

```
def self.by_status(status)
  case status
  when 'Running'  then where(running: true)
  when 'Finished' then where(success: true)
  when 'Queued'   then where(started_at: nil)
  else scoped #change this to all in Rails 4 since Model.all returns an AR Relation
  end
end
```

Comment: Fair. At some stage I think we'll move `status` in to the database so it's not calculated at run-time. But this is a good answer for the interim -- cheers.